# Can iCal scroll by week in month view?

Tags: ical, calendar, macos

It seems to be bad design that I can not just scroll down on the month view of Calendar, so that the grid just moves up.   Going prev/next through the months is very uncomfortable any time you are dealing with periods of time that span from one month to the next!

Any method to get this function?  Calendar/iCal has been around a while, they should have built this in -- it is a common and convenient feature.

Comment: Is this question about the OS X or iOS application or both?

Comment: I edited the title, as the question and tags only mention the OS X version of iCal/Calendar, but if you are indeed asking about the iOS version, please make your own edits to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

iCal is limited to the view modes you see in the main window - Day, Week, Month and Year. It's not very customizable.

However as an alternative, you might want to look at [BusyCal](http://www.busymac.com/busycal/). It's a pretty well regarded app. The two word pitch is "iCal Pro". It integrates with the system calendar, so all the built-in calendar based functions work fine, and in addition to iCloud sync, it has much better Google Calendar sync if that's a selling point. Most importantly for you it's more customizable in terms of views, and the **month view scrolls by week**.

Sorry there's nothing to be done with the existing app, but BusyCal is probably the best option to get what you want. There's a 30 day demo, so give it a try.

[image: BusyCal Interface]

Comment: good tip. I knew of that application, but then forgot about it. I have really been loving Fantastical, but that serves a different purpose -- a very handy pop-down-from-the-top-menu interface with natural language input

Comment: Yeah, Fantastical looks pretty good as well - I haven't bought it for my Mac, since I do most of my calendar input on my iPhone. Since both it and Busy Cal access the system calendar, they should work in conjunction just fine however.